# What would a Natario Warp Drive look like, outside & inside the warp bubble?

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, faster-than-light, warp-drives

Within a Natario Warp Metric, all mass in front of the ship is pushed outwards by it's negative energy density, this means no light would interact with the front of the ship at all. And since the Drive would be travelling away from the light behind it faster than light, would that mean that inside the ship, everything would appear pitch black? (perhaps with some additional blue / red shifting effects) 
 
Then, outside the ship, since no photons could interact directly with the ship, it would presumably appear like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPrVjwDxQPY) (minus the red capsule). If this is the case, would an observer seeing the ship approach notice nothing until it was next to them, followed by the "space warp" going both ways at the ships speed (e.g. 10c) Similiar to [tachyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon#/media/File:Tachyon04s.gif). Would an observer in a position behind the forward warp simply see the ship travelling off at its speed? (e.g. 10c) I am guessing there would be some kind of red / blue shift effects in reality. 
 
I understand this is a general and long winding question. But an answer to any of these would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's Jose Natario's paper, [Warp Drive With Zero Expansion](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0110086).

Comment: I have already read the paper. Although it is very interesting, it is primarily math, math I do not have the experience to understand. I asked this question in hope of an easier to understand explanation. Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: I didn't post that link as an answer to your question. I posted it to supply info to the people reading this question, including potential answerers.

Comment: Ah. Apologies. Still new-ish to the site.

Comment: I know that light can pass through an Alcubierre warp drive, so they aren't dark inside.   But i haven't looked at the Natario Warp drive, i'll have to check the maths.